# ENOENT error while trying to write to internal storage

Tags: android, storage

I'm trying to download a file from a web server and then save it to a folder inside within my apps folder in `data/data`. However, I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.package.name/databases/file: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

This is my code inside AsyncTask (copied from [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)):

```
   FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/file");
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: R u checking in emulator>>

Comment: use `FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: That works, but it saves the file to `files` folder. How do I save to a different folder?